# Getting Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Here is the init method on my game's main menu:

```
-(id) init {
if( (self=[super initWithColor:ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255)])) {

    // Get the screen dimensions
    int screenWidth = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width;
    int screenHeight = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].height;

    // Add the logo
    CCSprite* logo = [[CCSprite node] initWithFile:@"Ninjasplash2.png"];

    [logo setPosition:ccp(screenWidth/2.0,screenHeight * 0.65f)];

    [self addChild:logo];

    // Add the buttons
    CCMenuItemLabel   *startButton =
    [CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Start" target:self selector:@selector(onStart:)];
    startButton.color = ccBLACK;

    CCMenuItemLabel *quitButton =
    [CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Quit" target:self selector:@selector(onQuit:)];
    quitButton.color = ccBLACK;

    CCMenuItemLabel *optionsButton =
    [CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Options" target:self selector:@selector(onOptions:)];
    optionsButton.color = ccBLACK;

    CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:startButton, quitButton, optionsButton, nil];

    [menu alignItemsVertically];

    [menu setPosition:ccp(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight*0.25f)];

    [self addChild:menu];

    // Get the music started, yeh mon
   //[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"island.mp3" loop:true];
}

return self;
```

}

When trying to add the logo, i get the above mentioned error and I have absolutely no idea how to fix it.  It is getting incredibly frustrating.  If you need me to add more information please just let me know and I will be glad to.  Thank you.  Also, I've read it may have something to do with memory management and deallocating, but it won't even load this main screen so there is nothing to deallocate.

Stack Trace I believe:

```
#0  0x01956df5 in objc_release ()
#1  0x01957c60 in (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) ()
#2  0x01c8aed8 in _CFAutoreleasePoolPop ()
#3  0x002c4385 in CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch(unsigned long long, unsigned long long) ()
#4  0x002c41af in CA::Display::TimerDisplayLink::callback(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) ()
#5  0x01d2a966 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#6  0x01d2a407 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer ()
#7  0x01c8d7c0 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#8  0x01c8cdb4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#9  0x01c8cccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#10 0x02a20879 in GSEventRunModal ()
#11 0x02a2093e in GSEventRun ()
#12 0x00845a9b in UIApplicationMain ()
#13 0x000c6526 in main at /Users/MaristUser/Desktop/Ninja Run/Ninja Run/main.m:14
```

Comment: Do you get a stack trace?

Comment: I edited post with the stack trace

Comment: An access error is more often than not trying to reference an object in an array where either 1) the array doesn't exist or 2) the object in that array is null / doesn't exist. Nothing immediately jumps out at me above. Are you sure the error occurs in here? Have you stepped through with the debugger?

Comment: I think it happens _after_ the init method. The stack trace says it has to do with an auto released object, so I think the OP just forgot to retain an object in his/her init method. @Clever

Comment: Does `addChild:` retain the child?

Answer (score 0):

```
CCSprite* logo = [[CCSprite node] initWithFile:@"Ninjasplash2.png"];
```

change the above line to

```
CCSprite* logo = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"Ninjasplash2.png"];
```

or:

```
CCSprite* logo = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Ninjasplash2.png"];
```